# How to listen event on specific file in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am new to visual studio code API.

I would like to listen some event like onSave , onClose etc...

I am currently using this API.
But I think this is vary expensive like this. When you only need to listen event for only a specific file.

```js
let { workspace } = require("vscode");

module.exports = {
    activate(ctx) {
        ctx.subscriptions.push(
            workspace.onDidSaveTextDocument(({ fileName, version }) => {
                
            })
        )
    },
    deactivate() {}
};
```

Comment: how many files a second do you save?

Comment: "I think this is vary expensive like this", you'd better give some proof.

Comment: Every time If I save any file then it will fire this function. then check something if true then update else do something...Its take some CPU computation right ? So its  expensive

Comment: Its like watch all...check then do something...I want something like watch one! ...check then do something...so my code only run if a specific file change

Answer (score 1):

Not a great solution .But worked for me.
Still Though  is there any other way,The better way?...

My solution is...

```js
let onSaveCleaner = workspace.onDidSaveTextDocument((e) => {
    // watch for all file save event ... yuck!
});

let onCloseCleaner = workspace.onDidCloseTextDocument(({ fileName, languageId }) => {
    // some condition like once `specific` file closed 
    if (languageId == "python" && fileName == "...") {
        onSaveCleaner.dispose()
        onCloseCleaner.dispose()
    }
});
```

By doing that We only run expensive code when file is not closed!
Once the file closed...Destroy everything!

Comment: I think there is better API.Which I don't know...for watching specific file...not all file!

Comment: This does not work for notebooks.